# Newbie: Minimal program to display a PNG in a window

Tags: c++, qt4, png

All,

I must have a fundamental neuron missing, but I cannot get a simple program to load a PNG file and display it in a window.  I'm not sure if it is a QPixmap, a QPicture, or what. All of the samples in the QTCreator are a bit more than I need right now.  Baby steps...

I can get the window to display, and the program doesn't barf when I try to load the PNG, but it never gets displayed.

If someone would post a simple program to load a PNG from a file and display it, it would greatly appreciated.  (I know, asking a lot, but...).

Thanks!

:bp:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example is minimal: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/widgets-imageviewer.html

You will want to have a look at the function `ImageViewer::open()`:

1. Build a QImage object from a filename;
2. Convert your QImage to a QPixmap with `QPixmap::fromImage()`;
3. Put your QPixmap in a QLabel with `QLabel::setPixmap()`.

The QImage object will automatically chose an appropriate reader according to the format of the image it detects in step 1.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll start digging!  Much Appreciated!